# stair stepping text in html/css

Tags: html, css

Is there any best-practices way of stair stepping text on a website using HTML/CSS? The word
["and"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEMe5.png) illustrates the effect.

Comment: I don't think there is a best practices but there is a lot of methods

Comment: I believe this can be done by abusing `ruby`, but you would need to annotate each character in your HTML you want to move so they can be specifically selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the css property `vertical-align` with percentage values (cf. [this section on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)) . `0%` marks the default baseline, negative and positive values are supported.   This may not be a best practice of any kind but it serves the purpose and is flexible enough to support various 'step heights' and 'stair lengths'

A standalone example follows:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Stair Stepping</title>
            <style>
                html, body {
                    height: 100%;
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                }
                .step0 { vertical-align: -45%; }
                .step1 { vertical-align: -30%; }
                .step2 { vertical-align: -15%; }
                .step3 { vertical-align:   0%; }
                .step4 { vertical-align:  15%; }
                .step5 { vertical-align:  30%; }
                .step6 { vertical-align:  45%; }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <span class="step0">A</span><span class="step1">l</span><span class="step2">i</span><span class="step3">q</span><span class="step4">u</span><span class="step5">a</span><span class="step6">m</span> liquam cursus diam ut bibendum hendrerit. Vivamus dignissim egestas ullamcorper. Vestibulum dapibus ullamcorper neque, id hendrerit magna scelerisque eget. Quisque et elit urna. Pellentesque facilisis tempor lacus, dignissim fermentum odio rhoncus vel. Aenean vitae magna vitae purus volutpat posuere non vitae odio. Phasellus quam nulla, euismod ac consequat a, hendrerit ut diam. Nam diam urna, sollicitudin eu commodo pharetra, condimentum ut magna. Etiam rhoncus et lorem efficitur rhoncus. Duis ac nibh vehicula, laoreet sem non, congue mi. In eget fringilla metus. Donec nec nulla dui. Ut a bibendum orci.</p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to use nested elements then consider margin and alignment:

```css
.stair {
  font-size: 25px;
}

span {
  margin-bottom: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<span class="stair">A
<span>B
<span>C
<span>D
</span>
</span>
</span>
</span>
```

Or use transform:

```css
.stair {
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top:50px;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<span class="stair">A
<span>B
<span>C
<span>D
</span>
</span>
</span>
</span>
```