# How can I responsively diagonally overlay text across the page?

Tags: javascript, css, text, styling, text-styling

I'd like to have a custom error/loading page on my site which display the the error code or some dynamic text like *error* and *loading* diagonally in big bold letters across the page. Ideally, it'd work using only css but I don't mind place the letters with javascript if not possible. Also, I'd like the letters to overlap on smaller screen and I don't know how to get that working.

I thought about using absolute positioning but I'm not sure how to center the text since letter width changes. Maybe it's only possible with a different font?
Here's [a fiddle of what I mean](https://jsfiddle.net/Lymrbw4d/2/)

```
.digit {
  position: absolute;
}

.digit:first-child {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.digit:nth-child(2) {
  top: 50%;
  left: calc(50% - 1em);
}

.digit:last-child {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Otherwise, I'm thinking about centering the text and using letter spacing based on viewwidth and text length, but is there a way to offset single letters up and down?

Has someone come across something like this before? Or is there a better solution I haven't thought of?

Exemple of what I mean with diagonal letter placement.
[image: simplified output exemple]

Mobile exemple (I did with paint so the white background of the letters on top hide the ones on the bottom, but that's not a behavior I expect, the letters' background should be transparent):
[image: simplified mobile output exemple]

```css
.digit {
  font-size: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

.digit:first-child {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.digit:nth-child(2) {
  top: 50%;
  left: calc(50% - 1em);
}

.digit:last-child {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="error">
  <div class="code">
    <span class="digit">4</span>
    <span class="digit">0</span>
    <span class="digit">4</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I added a fiddle, does that help you answer the question?

Comment: Some ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51488508/stair-stepping-text-in-html-css. Or use skew() and rotate() CSS properties to turn the text and run it diagonally down the page; it won't be stair-stepped though but could work and won't need things like absolute positioning to work (will be more responsive).

Comment: here is an idea with flex for the alignement + a transition on hover for demo https://jsfiddle.net/x2r8qv7s/

Answer (score 1):

You can center element using this:

```
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

```css
.code {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.digit {
  font-size: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

.digit:nth-child(1){
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.digit:nth-child(2) {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.digit:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="error">
  <div class="code">
    <span class="digit">4</span>
    <span class="digit">0</span>
    <span class="digit">4</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Mobile version works fine for me

```css
.code {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.digit {
  font-size: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

.digit:nth-child(1){
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.digit:nth-child(2) {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.digit:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="error">
  <div class="code">
    <span class="digit">4</span>
    <span class="digit">0</span>
    <span class="digit">4</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I guess your numbers had background because of the font you used